# simple javascript path issue

Tags: javascript

I'm trying to nest some thumbnails within a drop menu that will appear in a different area of the page when activated. When I do, the JavaScript does not function properly.

```
$(document).ready(function(){

    $("h4").append('<em></em>')

    $(".thumbs a").click(function(){

        var largePath = $(this).attr("href");
        var largeAlt = $(this).attr("title");

        $("#largeImg").attr({ src: largePath, alt: largeAlt });

        $("h4 em").html(" (" + largeAlt + ")"); return false;
    });

});
```

The working markup:

```
<section class="group1">
             <h3>Print</h3>

                    <p class="thumbs">

                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                        <a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a>
                    </p>

           </section>
```

Not working in nested `<li>`:

```
<ul id="expandmenu">

                            <li>Digital

                                <ol>
                                    <p class="thumbs">

                                    <li><a class="clip" href="img/pen.png" title="awesome"><img src="images/picture1.jpg" /></a></li>
                                    <li><a target="iframe2" href="Change font color rainbow.htm">Rainbow Fonts</a></li>
                                    <li><a target="iframe2" href="Cookies_ShowUserName.htm">ShowUserName</a></li>

                                    </p>

                                </ol>

                            </li>

                        </ul>
```

Comment: There is no obvious reason why the latter would not work from what I can see. However, note it's invalid mark-up to have a `p` tag inside an `ol` tag. When you say it doesn't work, what happens? Any error in the JavaScript console inside Dragonfly/Firebug?

Comment: haha, you nailed it Utkanos, it was a HTML markup mistake, I simply moved the p class inside the <li> silly me, thanks for being another pair of eyes

Comment: Ah cool - I've posted it as an answer, then :)

Answer (score 0):

Probably because the HTML mark-up is invalid - you can't have a `p` tag inside a `ol` tag.